# Simple device_vector code gives std::bad_alloc : unknown

Tags: c++, cuda

I am getting following error:

```
std::bad_alloc: unknown error
abort (core dumped)
```

My code is

```
try {

thrust::host_vector<int> hvec(10);
thrust::generate(hvec.begin(), hvec.end(), rand);

thrust::device_vector<int> dvec = hvec; // this is where exception is thrown
thrust::sort(dvec.begin(), dvec.end());

} catch (thrust::system_error e)
{
    cout << e.what() << "\n";
}
```

I am using linux3.16 , nvcc V6.5.12 with NVidia GTX 750

I wrote another code to print memory info using cudaMemGetInfo. It prints following:

```
Free : 4203824
Total : 4470016
```

Comment: What would you expect should happen given `hvec` is an empty vector?

Comment: @talonmies point is valid: your `hvec` is created as an empty vector.  So your code isn't very sensible.  But I'm not sure that leads to the error you are seeing (although it may).  When I compile and run your code under linux, I get no errors of any kind (and it obviously isn't doing much).  But your memory info seems quite small.  Normally `cudaMemGetInfo` returns values in *bytes*.  Are you dividing these numbers in any way?  Because a total memory of 4470016 *bytes* (i.e. ~4MB) doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @talonmies : I tried with 10 size but it did not work so tried with empty vector(sorru about that) (edited the code).

Comment: @Robert I guess reboot is needed after installation of CUDA and thrust. After reboot the memory information shown is correct and the code is also working. thanks guys !!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments the memory information shown was wrong (around 4MB). I did not reboot after installation of CUDA and thrust. After reboot the code is working fine and the information shown by cudaMemGetInfo is also correct.